# C# Invalid JSON Primitive Reading from Cookie

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint-2013

I'm using JQuery.Cookie to store a javascript object as a cookie value:

```
    var refinerData = {};
// Read in the current cookie if it exists:
if ($.cookie('RefinerData') != null) {
    refinerData = JSON.parse($.cookie('RefinerData'));
}
// Set new values based on the category and filter passed in
switch(category)
{
    case "topic":
        refinerData.Topic = filterVal;
        break;
    case "class":
        refinerData.ClassName = filterVal;
        break;
    case "loc":
        refinerData.Location = filterVal;
        break;
}    
// Save the cookie:
$.cookie('RefinerData', JSON.stringify(refinerData), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
```

When I debug in firebug, the value of the cookie value seems to be formatted correctly:

{"Topic":"Disease Prevention and Management","Location":"Hatchery Hill Clinic","ClassName":"I have Diabetes, What can I Eat?"}

I'm writing a SharePoint web part in C# that reads the cookie in and parses it:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["RefinerData"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            string val = cookie.Value;
            // Deserialize JSON cookie:
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var refiners = serializer.Deserialize<Refiners>(cookie.Value);
           output.AppendLine("Deserialized Topic = " + refiners.Topic);
            output.AppendLine("Cookie exists: " + val);
        }
    }
```

I have a Refiners class for serializing to:

```
    public class Refiners
{
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

However, this code throws an "Invalid JSON Primitive" error.  I can't figure out why this isn't working.  One possibility is that its not reading the cookie correctly.  When I print out the value of the cookie as a string, I get:

%7B%22Topic%22%3A%22Disease%20Prevention%20and%20Management%22%2C%22Class%22%3A%22Childbirth%20%26%20Parenting%202013%22%2C%22Location%22%3A%22GHC%20East%20Clinic%22%7D

Answer (score 13):

Appears URL encoded, try decoding the value using the [`UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) method of the [`HtmlUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpUtility.aspx) (of which an instance is exposed by a page through the [`Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.server.aspx) property):

```
var refiners = serializer.Deserialize<Refiners>(Server.UrlDecode(cookie.Value));
```

Comment: Yes THANK YOU! that worked.  I had to make a slight adjustment to access Server.UrlDecode since its an Share Point webpart, but it worked wonderfully:

var refiners = serializer.Deserialize<Refiners>(HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(cookie.Value));

Comment: @user1231748 Of course, I should have given you that detail to access the static reference, my bad. Glad you got it going.

Comment: @user1231748  If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to decode the cookie prior to deserialization. Try using;

```
Refiners refiners = serializer.Deserialize<Refiners>(Server.UrlDecode(cookie.Value));
```